# UITextView autocorrection highlight animation glitch

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uitextview, autocorrect

I'm currently developing animated UITextView which has accessory controls on left side that can be expanded. Everything works fine so far except one detail - highlighting of autocorrect suggestions from iOS. If it's displayed on top of a text and I animate width change of UITextView - selection is left where it was.

Gif showing the problem:
[image]

I tried manually adding a flag for `setNeedsLayout()` and calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on superview. Nothing seems to help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Code gist resulting in same bug as described above: 
https://gist.github.com/Kamajabu/07153bb5c8977d73673aa6a7b4563d84

Comment: @Magnas added github gist resulting in same bug: https://gist.github.com/Kamajabu/07153bb5c8977d73673aa6a7b4563d84